# How do I determine if multiple items are selected in a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, operators

I think it's obvious what I'm trying to do, but if you don't understand, please ask.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1  && 2)
{
    label1.Text = "Sometext";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, it's not at all obvious what you're trying to do here - you want to set some label if the selected index is both 1 and 2?  Can you give a more elaborate description of what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to change property of Listbox if i select multiple items in Listbox.

Answer (score 8):

SelectedIndices is what you want if you have enabled multi-select.  You can also check the size of the SelectedItems property.

The documentation for ListBox.SelectedIndex states:

> For a standard ListBox, you can use this property to determine the index of the item that is selected in the ListBox. **If the SelectionMode property of the ListBox is set to either SelectionMode.MultiSimple or SelectionMode.MultiExtended (which indicates a multiple-selection ListBox) and multiple items are selected in the list, this property can return the index to any selected item.**

Try this

```
if( listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 1 )
{
    // multiple items are selected
}
```

Comment: if you think i didnt read msdn you're wrong, so no need for copy and paste.

Comment: Considering you gave next to no information in your question, don't be so bitter when someone tries to help you with their own free time.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in the answer? His response checks if more than 1 item is selected, which is what you asked.

Comment: It's considered useful to reference documentation in an answer, regardless of whether or not the person asking the question has read it.  Answers on StackOverflow are around to help everyone, not just the person asking the question.

Comment: Haha, wow, I can't believe this answer seemed to have offended you.  the fact that your example used the SelectedIndex property made it pretty reasonable to assume that you hadn't read the documentation.  If you had, then why didn't you say so or provide a better example?  How did you miss the SelectedIndices right under it on the same page.  Amazing.

Comment: because there were multiple selectxxxxxxxxx and i didnt know which one to pick for sure, you're rude btw.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count > 1) // I'd use to group all of your multi-selection cases
{
   if (listBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(1) && listBox1.SelectedIndices.Contains(2))
   {
     label1.Text = "Sometext";
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that the control is 0 based so if you're trying to select the first two options, you'll want to check for 0 (item 1) and 1 (item 2).

edit: modified to handle the requirement listed in comments. Note, there's probably a better way and there may even be a method for this built in (never used the multi-selection list box). But I built a function to handle so you don't have to do it for every scenario.

The function that does the work:

```
private bool CasesFunction(ListBox lbItem, List<int> validIndices)
{
     for (int index = 0; index < lbItem.Items.Count; index++)
     {
        if (lbItem.SelectedIndices.Contains(index) && !validIndices.Contains(index))
           return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

And how I used it:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count > 1)
      {
         List<int> MyCase = new List<int> { 0, 1 };

         if (CasesFunction(listBox1, MyCase))
         {
            label1.Text = "Sometext";
            return;
         }
         else
            label1.Text = "";

         MyCase = new List<int> { 1, 2 }; // can do other checks

         if (CasesFunction(listBox1, MyCase))
         {
            label1.Text = "Sometext 2";
            return;
         }
         else
            label1.Text = "";
      }
      else
         label1.Text = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I just pasted your code in and it seems to work, but I've selected all items in my listbox and it still works. How can I prevent it from working when items that shouldnt be selected are selected?

Comment: @Liger86 - Define "works" and "shouldnt be selected".  You clearly haven't told us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: nevermind, it was the third line of your code that helped me.